# import from oracle to mysql by using CTL

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, import, ctl

how can i import data from an oracle database to a mysql database by using CTL file (generate with Toad for oracle)? 
Thank in advance 
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

A CTL file would seem to imply that you were trying to use SQL*Loader to load the data.  SQL*Loader, though, is an Oracle-specific tool.  It only supports loading data into Oracle, it does not have functionality to load data into MySQL.  So I doubt that the control file that Toad generated would be useful.

If you have a control file, though, that would imply that you had a flat file of data to load (i.e. a comma-separated or tab-separated flat file of data for each table in the database).  Is that the case?  If so, just about every database out there has utilities for importing flat files.  I'm no MySQL expert, but I assume MySQL has such a utility.  Of course, you could also relatively easily write a small application to do the load in whatever language you're familiar with.